# How to execute stream processing only when there are at least N rows?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I have the following spark SQL/Streaming query at a Kafka consumer, how can I specify that the fetch should be conditional when the batch size reach a specific size N, otherwise the consumer should buffer the elements before processing, so whenever I want to execute my logic it is guaranteed that I have an exact `Dataset<VideoEventData>` of size N. Current code:

```java
Dataset<VideoEventData> ds = spark
      .readStream()
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", prop.getProperty("kafka.bootstrap.servers"))
      .option("subscribe", prop.getProperty("kafka.topic"))
      .option("kafka.max.partition.fetch.bytes", prop.getProperty("kafka.max.partition.fetch.bytes"))
      .option("kafka.max.poll.records", prop.getProperty("kafka.max.poll.records"))
      .load()
      .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING) as message")
      .select(functions.from_json(functions.col("message"),schema).as("json"))
      .select("json.*")
      .as(Encoders.bean(VideoEventData.class));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i want to execute my logic it is gurateed that i have an exact Dataset of size N

That's not possible in Spark Structured Streaming (and Spark in general) out of the box.

You have the following options:

1. Configure the Kafka consumer that sits behind the kafka source using the Kafka Consumer properties.
2. Buffer the rows yourself as part of a arbitrary stateful aggregation.
3. Write a custom source to handle the buffering itself.

For 2. I could use [KeyValueGroupedDataset.flatMapGroupsWithState](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.KeyValueGroupedDataset@flatMapGroupsWithState[S,U](outputMode:org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.OutputMode,timeoutConf:org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.GroupStateTimeout)(func:(K,Iterator[V],org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.GroupState[S])=%3EIterator[U])(implicitevidence$9:org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[S],implicitevidence$10:org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[U]):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[U]) with a state that would accumulate over "chunks" that would eventually give you the size N.

For 3. Implement a custom **stateful** streaming [Source](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/Source.scala#L28) that would implement `getOffset` and `getBatch` in a way that `getOffset` would only give offsets when there are at least `N` rows.

DISCLAIMER: I've never done either solution myself before, but they look doable.

Comment: Thanks I will give solution #2 a try

Comment: @HODEH Thanks for accepting the answer and...please update me on your development as I'm considering the same myself to see how much I was off base :)

Comment: i am still not able to implement solution #2 can you provide me with some help @JacekLaskowski

Comment: @HODEH What do you have already? Use gist.github.com or github.com to show the code.

Comment: thanks for ur reply this is what i have now https://gist.github.com/hodeh/3b8683752ac1e4c0ec1199429752af55

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by configuring the Kafka consumer itself. Set `fetch.min.bytes` to the minimum value you want to have. That will tell Kafka to wait until it has enough data.

There is a related setting, `fetch.max.wait.ms`, that controls how long Kafka will at most wait. This value is 500 ms by default. You can read more [here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/kafka-the-definitive/9781491936153/ch04.html).